# API for stock price data for commercial re-distribution?

Tags: programming, market-data, historical-data, currency, commodities

(I know there are existing questions on this topic, but none seem to be for commercial re-distribution use, so please keep this question active.)

It seems there are many websites offering API for stock market data.
I want to create a company so that I can sell my data analysis to other people.
Which website has reliable and cheap data for commercial re-distribution in your experience?
I am looking at US and other important country(Germany, France, UK, Japan, India, Australia) data's for:

1. Stocks price history and daily data going forward
2. Company financials like income statement
3. Commodity and currency data (historical and day wise going forward)

Please suggest good websites in the range of $50-$100 per month that will allow commercial re-distribution of data.

Comment: Dmitri, no. It does not have anything on re-distribution for commercial purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Reputable vendors that have these dimensions and would allow redistribution for the price you suggest do not exist.